Immediate window in VS 2022 - run method in debug mode
I just switched from VS 2017 to VS 2022.
When I try to run method from class library project in immediate window I get "An expression evaluation is already in progress." (with no results or errors displayed) or "The operation could not be completed" error.
This is how I called method in VS 2017 and had no issues with it:
? Exports.AssemblySettings.Set("05.07.2024","password")

Is there any other way to run methods in VS 2022 or what must I do to run It in debug mode same as before?

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/VS-2022-VBNET-Immediate-Window-design-t/10454014?entry=problem&space=8&q=Fakes

@HansPassant so It's not available anymore  ? I don't have Tweaks extension installed, bump. Thanks for info.

I did a simple test, but it didn't show the same situation as you. If possible, could you provide your complete code or a minimal demo that can reproduce this problem?

@Codyliang I allready did modifications in code of my class library so I don't use immediate window anymore. Thanks for response though.
